# How to delete data from Tarantool?

Tags: lua, tuples, tarantool

I want to delete data from Tarantool space by condition.
I want to achieve result equals to SQL-query:

```
DELETE from 'books' where 'timestamp'< 123456789
```

When I use this query it ends with **error**:  `Failed to allocate 16384 bytes in mempool for new slab`

I have got space `books`. I make:

```
books:delete(1)
```

it delete row but my space len increases:

```
books:len()
```

So how can I do it in Tarantool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase `memtx_memory` parameter in `box.cfg{}` to overcome the 'Failed to allocate' error for memtx spaces (the same for vinyl spaces and `vinyl_memory`):

```
box.cfg{
    <...>,
    memtx_memory = <...>,
    vinyl_memory = <...>,
    <...>,
}
```

I guess that you use vinyl engine. `<space object>:len()` or `<index object>:len()` is estimated as the number of statements in an LSM tree and may be greater than actual number of tuples in a space. A delete operation creates a statement in the LSM tree, so it increases the value of `:len()`.

If you need an exact number of tuples in a vinyl space, then use `:count()`, but it is better to avoid this, because its complixity is linear (full scan of the entire space, which may be very expensive for large spaces). See the [documetation](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/2.3/book/box/box_space/#box-space-len).